# Why is TLS slow?

Tags: python, performance, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

How much overhead should I expect SSL/TLS to add?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Python 3.4.3.

**test.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket
import ssl

with socket.socket() as server:
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(('', 8001))
    server.listen(1)
    while True:
        with server.accept()[0] as client:
            start = datetime.now()
            client = ssl.wrap_socket(client, 'key.pem', 'cert.pem', True)
            end = datetime.now()
            print('{:.0f}ms'.format((end - start).total_seconds() * 1000))
            client.send(b'hello')
            client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

Start the server

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
$ python3 test.py
```

And connect

```
$ for i in $(seq 20); do openssl s_client -cert cert.pem -key key.pem -connect localhost:8001; done 
$ # output shows TLSv1.2 is being used
```

*Even on the same host,* TLS negotiation is taking 15ms. When I remove TLS, I measure the entire connect, transfer, and shutdown to be < 1ms.

I don't have much experience here, but it this seems significantly slower than I would expect. That's many millions of clock cycles. It's slower than light to traveling from LA to New York.

(1) Is this performance on par with what I should expect? (2) What is limiting factor causing this performance? (3) Can I change this code to make initial TLS negotiation faster?

Comment: [This page](https://zoompf.com/blog/2014/12/optimizing-tls-handshake) claims 250-500ms is typical due to network latencies. 15ms seems fine on the same host (yes, it's probably using several million clock cycles as DH key exchange is known to be computationally intensive). The trick is to leave the connection open so you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 4):

In case of plain TCP you have a single TCP handshake (1 RTT) which is fully handled inside the OS kernel for minimal latency and resource usage.

Whereas with TLS and your code you have *additionally to this* a full TLS handshake all the time since your code does not do session reuse. This means 2 RTT just for the handshake and heavy cryptography for key exchange every time (impact depending on the cipher). And there is also an additional RTT for the ordered TLS shutdown on top of the (in-kernel) TCP shutdown.  Also way more data gets transferred than for a TCP handshake and the TLS handshake is fully done in user space which causes additional delays caused by scheduling, many system calls to read and write data and the context switches and copies between kernel and user space involved with these system calls. Also you setup a new SSL context every time including loading certificates etc which adds more unnecessary overhead.

All this overhead is done twice on the same system since you have client and server on the same system and you also use client certificates. 
Additionally you don't transfer only very few data (much less than needed for the TLS handshake alone) so you only measure the time needed for TLS handshake, i.e. the most expensive part of TLS. And, since you have a single threaded client and a single threaded server each of these might be the speed limit.

In other words: your benchmark is not reflecting the actual overhead of TLS vs. TCP in the common real world scenarios. But it shows that TLS has noticeable impact if used in a too simple way, i.e. without any optimizations typically done by applications doing a lot of TLS.

Comment: Context switches are measured in microseconds. And yes I'm going this on the same system, but it's a multi-core environment. And yes I'm not transferring data; I'm interested in the latency introduced by TLS to otherwise-fast network connections.

Answer (score 3):

- Because TLS does 7 TCP trips to establish the encryption layer
- Because there is crypto involved (RSA, DHE, ...)

15ms is really not that much.